# User authorization via login does not work

Tags: django, django-login

I try to log in, but I get the error: "`'str' object is not callable`". What can happen?

```
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
login="eeiguomfug"
pas="B6AFQJTK"
user = authenticate(username=login, password=pas)
login(request, user)
```

Comment: Your `login = "eei..."` overrides the `login` import, so `login(request, user)` does not make much sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You overrode `login` method with `"eeiguomfug"` string. Use `username` variable name instead:

```py
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
username="eeiguomfug"
pas="B6AFQJTK"
user = authenticate(username=username, password=pas)
login(request, user)
```